# JSON to Java object deserialization exception

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MatchingResponse {
    @JsonProperty(value = "Code")
    private String code;
    @JsonProperty(value = "Msg")
    private String message;
    @JsonProperty(value = "Id")
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty(value = "Date")
    private String date;
    @JsonProperty(value = "ClientIin")
    private String clientIin;
    @JsonProperty(value = "Similarity")
    private String similarity;
    @JsonProperty(value = "VendorName")
    private String vendorName;
}
```

This is my class. I`m trying to deserialize this JSON:

```
{
    "Code": "200",
    "Msg": "",
    "Id": 20148,
    "Date": "2023-08-01T15:21:13.9704572+06:00",
    "ClientIin": "888888888888",
    "Similarity": "0.007720462",
    "VendorName": "SomeName"
}
```

to my custom class with this code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
byte[] byteResponse = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent().readAllBytes();
MatchingResponse response = mapper.readValue(byteResponse, MatchingResponse.class);
```

but because of JSON has empty variable "Msg", I`m getting exception:

```
Cannot construct instance of `MatchingResponse` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"Code":"200","Msg":"","Id":20148,"Date":"2023-08-01T15:18:03.883337+06:00","ClientIin":"888888888888","Similarity":"0.0738383234","VendorName":"SomeName"}')
 at [Source: (byte[])""{\"Code\":\"200\",\"Msg\":\"\",\"Id\":20147,\"Date\":\"2023-08-01T15:18:03.883337+06:00\",\"ClientIin\":\"830921301593\",\"Similarity\":\"0.0738383234\",\"VendorName\":\"VisionLabs\"}""; line: 1, column: 1]
```

I tried creating JsonSetter:

```
@JsonSetter
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        if (message != null && message.isEmpty()) {
            this.message = null;
        } else {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
```

like this or tried creating deserializers:

```
public class MatchingResponseDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MatchingResponse> {
    public MatchingResponseDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public MatchingResponseDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public MatchingResponse deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        String code = getOptionalString(node, "Code");
        String message = getOptionalString(node, "Msg");
        int id = getOptionalInt(node, "Id");
        String date = getOptionalString(node, "Date");
        String clientIin = getOptionalString(node, "ClientIin");
        String similarity = getOptionalString(node, "Similarity");
        String vendorName = getOptionalString(node, "VendorName");

        return new MatchingResponse(code, message, id, date, clientIin, similarity, vendorName);
    }

    private String getOptionalString(JsonNode node, String fieldName) {
        JsonNode valueNode = node.get(fieldName);
        return (valueNode != null) ? valueNode.asText() : null;
    }

    private int getOptionalInt(JsonNode node, String fieldName) {
        JsonNode valueNode = node.get(fieldName);
        return (valueNode != null) ? valueNode.asInt() : 0; // Provide a default value if needed
    }
}
```

Set this deserializer to the class:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MatchingResponseDeserializer.class)
public class MatchingResponse {
```

This deserializer:

```
public class EmptyStringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    public EmptyStringDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public EmptyStringDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
        if (node.asText().isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return node.toString();
    }
}
```

I set to variable:

```
@JsonProperty(value = "Msg")
@JsonDeserialize(using = EmptyStringDeserializer.class)
private String message;
```

but none of it worked.

I tried use Gson, but get exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $
```

So my question is, how can I fix this error? How to work with empty JSON variables?

Comment: Try to convert `byteResponse` to a string before map it to an object

Comment: My guess will be that `ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT` is converting the empty string to an empty object but `Msg` is a `String` not an object, try remove it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using json as jsonString and use

```
MatchingResponse matchingResponse = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, MatchingResponse.class);
```

instead of byte[]

Comment: Before I used jsonString, but still get same exception

Answer (score 0):

try removing `@AllArgsConstructor`, a small test without Lombok works fine...

I guess there's some issue with missing `@JsonCreator` annotation on the constructor generated by Lombok.

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class MatchingResponse {
    @JsonProperty(value = "Code")
    private String code;
    @JsonProperty(value = "Msg")
    private String message;
    @JsonProperty(value = "Id")
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty(value = "Date")
    private String date;
    @JsonProperty(value = "ClientIin")
    private String clientIin;
    @JsonProperty(value = "Similarity")
    private String similarity;
    @JsonProperty(value = "VendorName")
    private String vendorName;

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setClientIin(String clientIin) {
        this.clientIin = clientIin;
    }

    public void setSimilarity(String similarity) {
        this.similarity = similarity;
    }

    public void setVendorName(String vendorName) {
        this.vendorName = vendorName;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getClientIin() {
        return clientIin;
    }

    public String getSimilarity() {
        return similarity;
    }

    public String getVendorName() {
        return vendorName;
    }
}



@Test
void deserialize() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MatchingResponse matchingResponse = mapper.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/msg.json"), MatchingResponse.class);

    assertNotNull(matchingResponse);
}
```

Comment: Removed @AllArgsConstructor and created manually getters and setter but it did not worked

Comment: try removing `mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);` as well

Comment: Removed it too, still same

Comment: did you remove the custom deserializer first?

Comment: and still same error message?

Comment: yes, i did this all and still same error message

Comment: try logging the repsonse body, perhaps the json is broken. Or test your code by loading the json from file as I did in my test case.

Comment: "{\"Code\":\"200\",\"Msg\":\"\",\"Id\":20163,\"Date\":\"2023-08-02T15:09:36.8303984+06:00\",\"ClientIin\":\"888888888888\",\"Similarity\":\"0.0738383234\",\"VendorName\":\"Name\"}" getting json like this

Comment: is it surrounded by ""? then it's a string body, not json... check your backend impl

Comment: What I need to do? Convert String to JsonNode object?

Comment: how did you get the log output? You'll need the plain response to check... try using a http client like curl and store the body in a file. Then check again if there are surrounding "" signs.

Comment: I tried to conver jsonString to MatchingResponse, but I added variable to Msg and it converted successfully. Like this: `String strResponse = "{\"Code\":\"200\",\"Msg\":\"1\",\"Id\":20119,\"Date\":\"2023-08-01T12:28:14.2199073+06:00\",\"ClientIin\":\"888888\",\"Similarity\":\"0.0738383234\",\"VendorName\":\"Name\"}";`

Comment: and you get the same error with "" as Msg value?

Comment: No, if Msg is not empty I don`t get this error

Comment: strange, no problem here with empty string in Msg... `@Test
    void deserialize() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String json = "{\"Code\":\"200\",\"Msg\":\"\",\"Id\":20163,\"Date\":\"2023-08-02T15:09:36.8303984+06:00\",\"ClientIin\":\"888888888888\",\"Similarity\":\"0.0738383234\",\"VendorName\":\"Name\"}";

        MatchingResponse matchingResponse = mapper.readValue(json, MatchingResponse.class);

        assertNotNull(matchingResponse);
    }`

Comment: I wroted response to file. Response is: `"{\"Code\":\"200\",\"Msg\":\"\",\"Id\":20168,\"Date\":\"2023-08-02T16:23:59.5574581+06:00\",\"ClientIin\":\"88\",\"Similarity\":\"0.0738383234\",\"VendorName\":\"name\"}"`

Comment: I tried to convert json to LinkedHashMap<String,Object> but get same error. So problem in jsonString?

Comment: try adding a test class with my test method and check there

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the JSON I was getting. If you output it in the console, it looked like this:

```
"{\"Code\":\"200\",\"Msg\":\"\",\"Id\":20181,\"Date\":\"2023-08-02T17:41:22.0568448+06:00\",\"ClientIin\":\"8\",\"Similarity\":\"0.0738383234\",\"VendorName\":\"name\"}"
```

And the JSON I needed looked like this:

```
{"Code":"200","Msg":"","Id":20119,"Date":"2023-08-01T12:28:14.2199073+06:00","ClientIin":"8","Similarity":"0.0738383234","VendorName":"name"}
```

It turns out I needed to remove the extra backslash and quotes at the beginning and end of the JSON. So I used this code to remove it:

```
    private static String removeExtraBackslashes(String input) {
    // Replace \" with "
    return input.replace("\\\"", "\"");
}

private static String removeFirstAndLastQuotes(String input) {
    return input.substring(1, input.length() - 1);
}
```

And everything worked!

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
byte[] byteResponse = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent().readAllBytes();
String jsonString = new String(byteResponse); // parse byte array to String
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(jsonString); // parse String to JsonNode
MatchingResponse response = mapper.treeToValue(rootNode, MatchingResponse.class); // parse JsonNode to your object
```

The mapper.readTree(jsonString) parses the string into a JsonNode, which is Jackson's tree model for `JSON.mapper.treeToValue(rootNode, MatchingResponse.class)` then converts this tree into your object.

Also, you don't need to enable `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT`. Jackson automatically converts empty strings in the JSON to empty strings in the object, not null.

Comment: didn't work, same error